# which DisplayPorts should I use, integrated graphics card's ports or NVIDIA's ports?

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, performance

My Dell Precision 3630 (Intel Core Processor i7-9700K (8 Core, 8T, 12 MB Cache,3.6 GHz, 4.90 GHz Turbo, 95 W )  Intel UHD Graphics 630) has two integrated graphic card displayport ports. It also has 4 mini-displayport ports from its nVIDIA Quadro P620 graphics card. I am going to use 4 monitors. which ports should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a discrete graphics card then you should connect the monitors to the discrete graphics card.